# Does "A Steep Learning Curve" mean learn fast or learn in a hard way?

Tags: meaning

How do I understand the phrase *a steep learning curve*?

I feel confused about it. Does it mean **someone learns something fast** or **something is difficult for someone to learn**?

Comment: Learning is uphill. The hill is steep.

Comment: There is another (better) answer here:
[https://english.stackexchange.com/a/6226/351969](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/6226/351969)

Answer (score 4):

A **Learning Curve** is a graph depicting relationship between learning and amount of effort. And the learning is the outcome.

Steep refers to a slope rising or falling sharply and is almost perpendicular. It's very difficult to climb steep curve or mountain and takes lots of efforts and time.

Therefore, “*A Steep Learning Curve*” refers to something difficult to learn.

From the [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/6209/235205) asked on our [sister site English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com)

> In informal usage, a "steep learning curve" means something that is difficult (and takes much effort) to learn. It seems that people are thinking of something like climbing a steep curve (mountain) — it's difficult and takes effort.

Comment: This explanation suggests that the shorter the learning time, the steeper the curve, which is sort of the opposite of the meaning.

Comment: @fixer1234 the original meaning of a "learning curve" is learning vs experience/time, thus something learned quickly will be steeper, but we tend to use it the opposite way

Comment: The learning curve relates to the amount of effort required to achieve something, not the amount of time. Regardless of whether you take it slowly and gently, or whether you take it fast and hard, a given amount of effort does not produce a lot of progress.

Comment: @JavaLatte `Here time refers to efforts we put like studying, practicing etc.`

Comment: ... but it's **nothing** to do with time!!! If I sit with a maths book on my lap in front of the television for an hour, is that the same amount of effort as spending an hour carefully working out and writing down solutions to difficult maths problems? Of course it's not! The term is often used about situations where somebody has to work very hard for a fixed period of time, for example "His first day in his new job was a steep learning curve". it's the amount of effort that's important, not the time, and you have confused people by mentioning time at all.

Comment: @eques the *steepness* here includes the flat part before the steep :) Something with a steep learning curve doesn't have to be more difficult or take more time to master, but it'll leave you with a lower skill until you get over the "ledge". To someone in (most of) Europe, for example, (written) English won't have a very steep difficulty curve because they can learn one word, then another, then a phrase, then sentence structure, etc. Chinese will, because you have to learn a wholly new writing system before you can write *anything*.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski I'm not sure what point you are trying to make. My comment over 3 years ago was that how we use a "learning curve" is opposite from what the term originally meant namely a relationship between experience and skill, so steeper meant learned faster (i.e. less time to achieve a skill level)

Comment: "The learning curve relates to the amount of effort required to achieve something, not the amount of time. Regardless of whether you take it slowly and gently, or whether you take it fast and hard, a given amount of effort does not produce a lot of progress."

If effort is the horizontal axis & learning is the vertical axis, then a steep slope means that a small amount of effort results in a large amount of learning. Which is the opposite of the typical intended meaning in modern usage.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this has already been stated but I wonder if, from a mathematical standpoint (keeping with the graph metaphor), we consider learning as work.  We will keep that on the y-axis and then have time represented on the x-axis.  Then let us take the example of learning to fly a plane (a very difficult skill to master).  Whether you learn to be a master pilot over your entire life or within a few years, the amount of work needed to learn the skill is the same.

Taking the analogy further, let us say that a war is about to break out and we need pilots tomorrow.  We could say that the learning curve is steep for this learning process.  Later, the war ends and someone wishes to learn to fly for enjoyment.  They have the opportunity to learn over their entire lifetime.  We could say that this leisure process would have a much flatter learning curve.  Both end up expending the same amount of effort to learn to fly but one had a steeper learning curve than the other did.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is a colloquial use of the term 'steep learning curve' and a literal one.
The former is used to describe being required to learn a difficult thing in a notably short time frame. Literally though, by definition more difficult things take longer to learn, so plotting a 'learning curve' would look less steep for more difficult tasks.  'Effort' shouldn't really be considered, since it goes without saying that the more effort you apply the faster you will learn anything.  It doesn't tell us anything about the objective difficulty. The question should be considered as 'all other things equal (including effort)', which of these two things has a steeper learning curve?  The answer depends on whether you use the colloquial or literal definition, and the answers will be opposite, hence the confusion around the term.

Answer (score 0):

The vast majority of people who say "steep learning curve" know nothing about mathematics or steep or curve.  What they mean is that it will take time and require effort to learn.  That's all it means.  You need not consult mathematicians for the answer.  If you feel this is a mathematics question you've come to the wrong forum.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, a "*steep* **learning-curve**" means that the time required to learn something is relatively faster than a protracted, or shallow, learning-curve required by another subject; for example, without any prior experience in both subjects, it will be much easier for most people to learn how to ride a bike than to learn how to fly an airplane- therefore the learning-curve of learning how to ride a bike is much steeper than learning how to fly an airplane.

[image]

Comment: While this may be the case, it is generally used to mean something that is hard to learn - i.e., the yellow line doesn't need to reach as high, so the blue line is steeper and thus more difficult.

Comment: Oh @petersmith, my friend- that is incorrect; [many, many programmers concur](https://twitter.com/mpa000/status/907653776047312896) with my clarification- blessings!

Comment: Yes, that may be the correct term; however, it is not the usage in common language, thus it is becoming not the correct term. [`The popular meaning of "steep learning curve" is "difficult to learn"; the technical meaning is "quick to learn".`](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/6226/222219)

Comment: [Is Ruby on Rails supposed to have a steep learning curve or is it just me | Do a screencast or online learning course. Michael Hartl's tutorial is good, but very steep learning. I found that the books above, plus Codeschool course on RSpec, helped me get through it - but I still had to reach out to the author on a couple of small points.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25369/is-ruby-on-rails-supposed-to-have-a-steep-learning-curve-or-is-it-just-me/210916).  I'm sorry @StephenS S, but I'm afraid your answer is still incorrect.

Comment: [I might add that our brothers and sisters at the Stack Exchange: English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6212/whats-the-opposite-for-steep-learning-curve/75143) share my same position.  Thank ya.

Comment: Unless I'm misinterpreting what you are saying and we actually agree, they don't. Both the post you just linked and the one I linked earlier state that a steep learning curve is something hard to learn. The one you linked is asking for something that is easy to learn, aka, the opposite of a steep learning curve.